# How to prevent the configuration files change by mistake

Tags: java, server, configuration

We have quite large system consists of some parts - some webapps deployed on application server, some standalone processes (working in the background as daemon or system services), some standalone applications.

All of them use custom configuration retrieved from external files with different format. Webapps usually use standard Java property pattern - `name=value`. Other processes rather use custom format usually based on XML but not always.

**My question is how to make technical prevention for any change made by mistake in such configuration files?**

The first (and maybe little immature) solution would be to install any VCS - Version Control System (Git, Mercurial) on the server. And make local repository in the place where configuration files are located.
This of course doesn't prevent any mistake, but provides configuration change versioning and helps find changes.
Does it exist any better solution? I prefer simple solutions.

*More info:*

*Windows Server; Tomcat as web application container; standalone processes written in Java; configuration files located externally in single, common directory;*

Comment: Technical prevention as in throw an error when keys in the property file are not expected? Or errors when entering values which are not expected?

Comment: I think that the best is throwing an error after unintended, unconfirmed or disapproved changes. Validation of values entered in configuration file is to hard so I don't expect such solution is possible.